# Weirdness using the raspberry pi pico uart with the c sdk

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, embedded, microcontroller, raspberry-pi-pico

I am extremely disconcerted.

I'm making a remote controlled machine using a pi pico to drive the motors and read some sensors, and a raspberry pi 4 to send commands to the pi pico via serial and host the web interface.

The following code seems to work... but... If I remove the if with uart_is_writable coding and its content it doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/uart.h"
#include "hardware/irq.h"

//DEFINES
#define UART_ID uart0
#define BAUD_RATE 19200
#define DATA_BITS 8
#define STOP_BITS 1
#define PARITY    UART_PARITY_NONE
#define UART_TX_PIN 0
#define UART_RX_PIN 1
#define LED_PIN PICO_DEFAULT_LED_PIN

static int chars_rxed = 0;

volatile char uCommand[32] = {0, 0};

void on_uart_rx(void) {
   char tmp_string[] = {0, 0};
   new_command = true;
   while (uart_is_readable(UART_ID)) {
       uint8_t ch = uart_getc(UART_ID);
       tmp_string[0] = ch;
       strcat(uCommand, tmp_string);
       if(uart_is_writable(UART_ID)){
         uart_putc(UART_ID, '-');
         uart_puts(UART_ID, uCommand);
         uart_putc(UART_ID, '-');
       }
       chars_rxed++;
   }
}

int main(){

 uart_init(UART_ID, BAUD_RATE);

 gpio_set_function(UART_TX_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_UART);
 gpio_set_function(UART_RX_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_UART);

 uart_set_hw_flow(UART_ID, false, false);

 uart_set_format(UART_ID, DATA_BITS, STOP_BITS, PARITY);

 uart_set_fifo_enabled(UART_ID, false);

 int UART_IRQ = UART_ID == uart0 ? UART0_IRQ : UART1_IRQ;

 irq_set_exclusive_handler(UART_IRQ, on_uart_rx);
 irq_set_enabled(UART_IRQ, true);

 uart_set_irq_enables(UART_ID, true, false);

 uart_puts(UART_ID, "\nOK\n");

   while (1){
       tight_loop_contents();
       if(uCommand[0] != 0){
         uart_putc(UART_ID, '/');
         uart_puts(UART_ID, uCommand);
         memset(uCommand, 0, sizeof(uCommand));
       }
     }

}
```

Comment: Without context, t's not clear to me why you expect that it would work. I assume that it was added for some purpose, and that the other side cares about that information that you send back.

Comment: Thomas Jager that little piece was taken from the raspberry example, it would theoretically serve to send back the read character. Removing it should not affect the code, but it does, providing a different output, as if it exited the interrupt and interpreted a single send several times.

Comment: Which specific example is this from?

Comment: Thomas Jager https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/uart/uart_advanced

Comment: Is there code on the other side interpreting things, or are you typing directly into a serial console?

Comment: Im using Arduino serial prompt for typing and receiving

Comment: It is unclear how the uart is configured, specifically the TX interrupt. If it is enabled, it _seems_ that the empty TX buffer triggers the ISR, and if you don't write anything it is triggered constantly.

Comment: Test one side with a known good source, then the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code you linked to is for a simple tty/echo implementation.

You'll need to tweak it for your use case.

Because Tx interrupts are disabled, all output to the transmitter has to be polled I/O. Also, the FIFOs in the uart are *disabled*, so only single char I/O is used.

Hence, the `uart_is_writable` to check whether a char *can* be transmitted.

---

The linked code ...

echos back the received char in the Rx ISR. So, it needs to call the above function. Note that if Tx is *not* ready (i.e. full), the char is *not* echoed and is *dropped*.

I don't know whether `uart_putc` and `uart_puts` check for ready-to-transmit in this manner.

So, I'll assume that they do *not*.
This means that if you call `uart_putc/uart_puts` and the Tx is full, the current/pending char in the uart may get trashed/corrupted.

So, `uart_is_writable` should be called for any/each char to be sent.

Or ... `uart_putc/uart_puts` *do* check and will *block* until space is available in the uart Tx fifo. For you use case, such blocking is *not* desirable.

---

What you want ...

*Side note:* I have done similar [product/commercial grade] programming on an RPi for motor control via a uart, so some of this is from my own experience.

For your use case, you do *not* want to echo the received char. You want to append it to a receive buffer.

To implement this, you probably want to use ring queues: one for received chars and one for chars to be transmitted.

I assume you have [or *will* have] devised some sort of simple packet protocol to send/receive commands. The Rpi sends commands that are (e.g.):

1. Set motor speed
2. Get current sensor data

The other side should respond to these commands and execute the desired action or return the desired data.

Both processors probably need to have similar service loops and ISRs.

The Rx ISR just checks for space available in the Rx ring queue. If space is available, it gets a char from the uart and enqueues it. If no Rx char is available in the uart, the ISR may exit.

The base level code service loop should:

1. Check if the uart Tx can accept another character (via `uart_is_writable`) and, if so, it can dequeue a char from the Tx ring queue [if available] and send it (via `uart_putc`). It can loop on this to keep the uart transmitter busy.
2. Check to see if enough chars are received to form a packet/message from the other side. If there *is* such a packet, it can service the "request" contained in it [dequeueing the chars to make more space in the Rx ring queue].
3. If the base level needs to *send* a message, it should *enqueue* it to the Tx ring queue. It will be sent [eventually] in the prior step.

---

Some additional thoughts ...

The linked code *only* enables Rx interrupts and runs the Tx in polled mode. This may be enough. But, for maximum throughput and lowest latency, you may want to make the Tx interrupt driven as well.

You may also wish the enable the FIFOs in the uart so you can queue up multiple characters. This can reduce the number of calls to the ISR and provide better throughput/latency because the service loop doesn't have to poll so often.